# My query returns a lot of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's say I have this kind of structure in my database:

```
Table Grandparent (Id, Name)
Table Parent (Id, GrandparentId, Name)
Table Child (Id, ParentId, Name)
```

This is not a real structure, just theory... (considering the fact that this structure can be replaced with 1 Person table with parentId in it, yes I know). And of course let's suppose there are no genders... only ancestor and descendant, that's it.

Okay. So. Let's say these tables are classified by age. Old people go to the grandparent table. Middle age people go to the parent table, children go to the children table.

So how can I query all the children belonging to one grandparent?

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM Child
JOIN Parent ON Child.ParentId = Parent.Id
JOIN Grandparent ON Parent.Id = Grandparent.GrandParentId
WHERE Grandparent.GreatGrandParentId = 1;
```

Actually it works, but returns a lot of columns (not rows, columns). Little annoying but I can live with that. I'd be glad for any improvements. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably only want the columns from the `Child` table, rather than all the columns across all the tables in your query. Luckily, this is straightforward to achieve. Simply use `Child.*` instead of `*`, resulting in:

```
SELECT Child.* FROM Child
JOIN Parent ON Child.ParentId = Parent.Id
JOIN Grandparent ON Parent.Id = Grandparent.GreatGrandParentId
WHERE Grandparent.GreatGrandParentId = 1;
```

Comment: And shouldn't I use full outer join or any other join type?

Comment: No, the inner join you're using is fine, as you only want matching rows. That is, you don't care about something in `Child` with no matching `Parent` or a `Parent` with no matching `Grandparent`.

Answer (score 1):

Select * will return all the columns from all the tables.

Specify which columns you want - e.g SELECT child.Name FROM ....